# How do I set up my Linux server to connect to repository?

Tags: git, ssh, server

I am a relatively inexperienced developer trying to take over the development of a website from the previous coders.

The code exists on a repository on Github and the website is hosted on a Linux server. I can log remotely into the server as a non-root user and run a `sudo git pull origin master` command but it won't work because of a permission denied error from Github. There is already an `~/.ssh` directory with `authorized_keys`, `known_hosts` as well as `id_rsa` files.

I've tried adding the keys there to my Github account and also tried using newly generated keys but it didn't work and I'm not even sure if adding these keys to my account is supposed to work. My account does have access to the repository, but I'm not sure if that is how it works.

Could anyone tell me what I need to do in order to make it possible for me to pull the code from the Github repository to this remote server?

Comment: While this rule has nothing to do with Git, it has a lot to do with Linux: try to use `sudo` as little as possible. You do not need it to run basic Git commands.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't always use sudo, but I think it was necessary for this command as I got a Bad user error without it.

Comment: Correction: I thought so. I was wrong, and it might have been what caused my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the command with sudo, you are using credentials stored in `/root`.
Make sure that:

- The command `git remote -v` executed in the repository folder shows you an SSH URL (`git@github.com:aUser/aRepository`)
- The SSH keys are in /root/.ssh
- The authentication work with `sudo ssh -Tv git@github.com`.
  You should see a welcome message like:

  ```
  Hi Me! 
  You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
  ```

In general, it would be better if you do all those command with a remote user account instead of the remote `root` account.

---

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246089/discussion-between-samson-daniel-and-vonc), it appears that:

- sudo is not needed
- keys are in `/home/company_name`
- permissions of `/home/company_name/.ssh` need [to be fixed](https://serverfault.com/a/253314)

What the OP had:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 [company_name] [company_name] 2.2K Mar 8 2019 known_hosts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 [company_name] [company_name] 38 Mar 8 2019 config
-rw------- 1 [company_name] [company_name] 755 Mar 17 2019 authorized_keys
-rw-r--r-- 1 [company_name] [company_name] 402 Dec 6 2019 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 [company_name] [company_name] 1.7K Dec 6 2019 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 [company_name] [company_name] 746 Jun 29 08:46 id_rsa_samson.pub
-rw------- 1 [company_name] [company_name] 3.2K Jun 29 08:46 id_rsa_samson
drwx------ 2 [company_name] [company_name] 4.0K Jun 29 08:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 [company_name] [company_name] 4.0K Jun 29 09:20 ..
```

Versus the right permissions for SSH:

| Path | Permission |
| --- | --- |
| .ssh directory ([code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2dc328023f60212cd29504fc05d849133ae47355/regress/check-perm.c#L131)) | 0700 (drwx------) |
| private keys (ex: `id_rsa`) ([code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2dc328023f60212cd29504fc05d849133ae47355/regress/check-perm.c#L131)) | 0600 (-rw-------) |
| `config` | 0600 (-rw-------) |
| public keys (*.pub ex: `id_rsa.pub`) | 0644 (-rw-r--r--) |
| `authorized_keys` ([code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2dc328023f60212cd29504fc05d849133ae47355/regress/check-perm.c#L131)) | 0644 (-rw-r--r--) |
| `known_hosts` | 0644 (-rw-r--r--) |

From there, a ssh -Tv git@github.com does display the expected welcome message `Hi <You>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

Any `git clone/push/pull` will work (again, no `sudo` needed)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have confirmed that `git remote -v` shows an ssh url and like I said there are ssh keys in the root folder (~). But when I run `sudo ssh -Tv git@github.com` the authentication fails. The debug log shows a whole lot of failed authentication attempts trying different keys. I think that the keys are either outdated or not set for the user that I am logged in as.

Comment: @SamsonDaniel Is the "`root folder (~)`" equals to `/root`? Because if it is not, that won't work (`sudo xxx` will look in `/root/.ssh`)

Comment: It doesn't say /root as far as I can tell but the debug log does say: `Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1`

Comment: @SamsonDaniel Do you see your keys, that you have created, in `/root/.ssh`?

Comment: Yes I can. Though I'm not sure how to check how my current user is set up. `authorized_keys` only has one key ending with the email of the previous developer, but I am not logged on his account, so maybe that is the problem.

Comment: @SamsonDaniel `authorized_keys` is only for the remote server. Since you contact github.com, the local `authorized_keys` does not matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246089/discussion-between-samson-daniel-and-vonc).